# How can I move a mysql database to another host, preserving the users/passwords?

Tags: mysql, hosting

So picture a regular Hostgator or similar account: everything done through Cpanel, a normal shared hosting website. There are static pages on the site, as well as an application (say Wordpress for instance) that relies on a mysql database.

Is there a way to move that website to a different host while keeping the same mysql users, and thus not breaking the application?

I mean, I can move the files via FTP, I can backup the database using phpMyAdmin and restore to the other server, but if it's assumed that I don't have access to whatever the original mysql user's password is, how can I switch hosts without breaking the application?

All the best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User ACLs are stored in a database called 'mysql'. As long as you backup that db and the versions of mysql on both hosts are reasonably similar, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Backup Wizard in cPanel, you can select Full Website Backup and send this backup file (which contains files, email accounts, MySQL users, databases etc.) to your new hosting provider who can then restore this backup onto their server.  This will avoid MySQL users being lost and your account settings will remain intact.